# Added row is not visible until scrolling

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I've built a simple master - detail form consisting of a form for the master element and table for the details.

In the toolbar of panel collection around the table I placed a CreateInsert button which ads a row to the table. My problem is that I this row is invisible until after I move my cursor over to the table and scroll down. Then it appears.

Before that a small scrollbar appear after pressing the button which can't be pressed.

Related to this is the problem when I press the delete button in the details, the table gets cut in half. I suspect these two problems are related.

This is my table:

[image: Table]

This is after I press CreateInsert. The table should add another row below this one, and it does, but it is not visible until after I scroll. This happens only for the first row.

I am using JDeveloper 12c with Oracle ADF Fusion Web Applications.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer I know , but try to programmatically refresh the PanelCollection and its container.

```
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
   .addPartialTarget (getThePanelCollection());
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
   .addPartialTarget (getThePanelCollectioncontainerLayout());
```

I tried this myself and it solved the problem after trying many other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Did u check with the Size.?
Try giving Styles for Table and Panel Collection "StyleClass=AFStretchWidth"

Answer (score -1):

1. Add **Execute** in binding side of the jspx page for the particular table
2. Add invoke action for the execute in executables
3. Change the properties to **render model** in refresh condition of the invoke action

It will automatically make the master table to trigger the new values
Thanks